# `du` shows non zero size of empty catalog

Tags: partitioning, files, filesystem, disk-usage, hidden-files

I know, that when I create empty catalog it has his own size:

```
mkdir test && du -h test
```

gives:

```
4,0K    test
```

But this case is another. I had catalog with 1e6 files (74 GB) on external HDD (ext4). I processed these files, saved in other catalog and deleted from this location in parallelized script. Now this catalog should be empty. So it is ok that

```
ls -a raw/all
```

print

```
.  ..
```

But

```
du -h raw/all
```

gives

```
19M     raw/all
```

Without `-h` we have exactly 19288B. And this is also strange result:

```
ls -la raw/all

total 19292
drwxr-xr-x 2 daniel daniel 19746816 wrz 18 19:23 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 daniel daniel     4096 wrz 17 13:21 ..
```

What is going on? Is there any cache in `du` command? Or after processing such many files there are any rest after these files? I deleted filed by `unlink` in perl5 script.

### Update - answers to questions from comments

```
ls -aiR raw/all
raw/all:
51647758 .  51647760 ..

lsof +L1
```

prints 44 lines but nothing connected with this catalog. But `lsof` gives something with numbers like `19746816`.

```
lsof | grep raw
bash      5355                daniel  cwd       DIR               8,17  19746816   51647758 /media/daniel/f2971ccd-4841-4da3-8ce3-d9f2cc03fc27/daniel/pro/scraper/raw/all
lsof      5677                daniel  cwd       DIR               8,17  19746816   51647758 /media/daniel/f2971ccd-4841-4da3-8ce3-d9f2cc03fc27/daniel/pro/scraper/raw/all
grep      5678                daniel  cwd       DIR               8,17  19746816   51647758 /media/daniel/f2971ccd-4841-4da3-8ce3-d9f2cc03fc27/daniel/pro/scraper/raw/all
lsof      5679                daniel  cwd       DIR               8,17  19746816   51647758 /media/daniel/f2971ccd-4841-4da3-8ce3-d9f2cc03fc27/daniel/pro/scraper/raw/all
```

Laptop was rebooted. External drive was disconnected. But `du` still shows `19M`.

Comment: try to `ls -aiR raw/all`(https://askubuntu.com/questions/15419/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-tree-a-directory-and-its-subdirs)

Comment: I'm curious if you run `sync` if that changes the size reported by `du`. Also any chance some file(s) are help open and can't be fully removed? Maybe check `lsof` for open files?  
`lsof +L1` to list open deleted files, found here: https://serverfault.com/questions/232525/df-in-linux-not-showing-correct-free-space-after-file-removal#232526

Comment: I think this is related to the fact that the directory own now 78GB worth  of Inodes and have to keep a huge list of  thoses, which size is 19MB

Comment: Maybe there are hidden files, listed by `ls -a` (part of the suggestion in Redbob's comment)

Comment: @sudodus Not, there was no any hidden file. I shows `ls -a` output in my question.

Comment: Then I think muru's comment contains the answer.

Comment: @sudodus Yes. In my opinion too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directories in ext4 filesystems grow, but don't shrink. So, if at some point it had to take up 19M for storing details of files in it, it will retain that much space even if those files were deleted. If you want to shrink a now-empty directory, delete and recreate it:

```
rmdir foo && mkdir foo
```

Or, retaining permissions:

```
mkdir foo2
chown --reference=foo foo2
getfacl foo | setfacl --set-file=- foo2
rmdir foo
mv foo2 foo
```

Source:

- [Unix & Linux: Why is this empty directory 3.5MB?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86985/70524)