# How to achieve List/Tree view in Nautilus?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

How to achieve List/Tree view in Nautilus like the following screenshot?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKSOd.png]

Cant find information about this.
ps
Im using Ubuntu Remix with pure Gnome 3, and last version of Nautilus.

Comment: Definitely not - there is no even word 'tree' on that page.

Comment: Well, maybe you right about naming, but anyway point of my question is different than in one by your link.

Comment: They've decided to remove the 'tree like' view.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the "List View" in Nautilus up to v3.4 (shipped with Ubuntu 12.10). It's no longer available in Nautilus v3.6

You can activate it in the "View" menu:

[image: Screenshot of the Naulius View menu]

Comment: Sadly that they removed this feature.

Comment: @Aditya Tried solution from second question - no luck. What do you meant exactly? Im already using list-view in all folders, through standard settings. Use of terminal command was not change anything for me.

Comment: @Aditya in modern version (which i use) Nautilus list-view does not provide tree-view: http://i.imgur.com/5YqccTA.png

Comment: Why, god oh why, was this feature removed? What was the reasoning? Am I alone in finding these constant dismaying decisions infuriating? My energy has just been zapped by this. Desperate. I want to rage quit. I forgive you Windows. The next time I feel the urge to complain about you I will try my very best to bite my tongue.

Comment: @BullfrogBlues second you

Comment: @BullfrogBlues Glory to KDE and Dolphin! I moved to it and found all features that I was need. I hope they will not follow that trend and will not cut off all cool functionality for touch usabilty advance. PS - how Windows connected to this - its explorer doesnt have tree-view too.

Comment: Totally agree. This is Ubuntu apeing Apple: customisability removed for one-size-fits-all 'clean interface'. IMO Windows Explorer has never been bettered.

Comment: The feature is there in the Arch distribution of Nautilus 3.10.0, I'd be surprised if the Ubuntu devs have removed it from the Ubuntu distribution. In GNOME Shell you click the "Files" drop-down menu in the top left when Nautilus has focus, then Preferences/Display has a "Navigate folders in a tree" checkbox.

Comment: Yes, the feature was reinserted since version 3.7.90: `Add back a Treeview option for list view. This is off by default, and is backed by a checkbox in the Preferences dialog` ([source](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/X11/GNOME/core/3.7/3.7.90/NEWS))

Comment: Confirmed this feature is back in 13.10

Comment: Confirmed for 20.04: Preferences > Views has a checkbox to "Allow folders to be expanded" under **List View**

Answer (score 35):

You can do this in the Nautilus (Also called "Files") preferences window. Here's how:

1. Make sure you have "Files" (program) running (or else the menus will NOT bring you the correct sub menus when you click on them)
2. Click **Edit** > **Preferences**
3. On the **Views** tab, select the **List View** viewing option next to "View new folders using:" and click close.

You're done!

[image: Nautilus preferences window]

Comment: This used to work, unfortunately I can not find this preferences dialog in 13.04.  I used `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-folder-viewer 'list-view'` instead.

Comment: This functionality has been restored in 13.10

Comment: Also, in the Files app in the menu Edit->Preferences Under the "Display" tab you want to check the "Navigate folders in a tree" checkbox

Answer (score 21):

`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-folder-viewer 'list-view'`

Options are `'list-view'`, `'icon-view'` and `'compact-view'`.

Comment: just what i was looking for, works great (can you tell me where I can find more info)

Comment: How to make this setting have a permanent effect? It is not permanent on 14.04 (not for me).

Comment: 14.04 click the settings "gear" on the right, then you'll find the Preferences in which you can select the list view.

Answer (score 17):

The tree view can be enabled from the files > preferences. There is a check box for this.

Version : 3.8.2

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Open Nautilus go to Edit ► Preferences then under Display tab checked:

**List View**
[image]Navigate folders in a tree

[image]

And also In Views tab select "List View" mode and close. Close and open Nautilus again see the changes.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

### Ubuntu 20.04, 18.04, and 17.10

1. Enable list view if it's not already enabled: Click the "Toggle view" button at top right.

   - If list view is already enabled, the button will look like a grid of squares: [image: Screenshot of button]

     If icon view is enabled, the button will look like a bulleted list: [image: Screenshot of button]
2. Enable tree view: Go to Files menu -> **Preferences** -> **Views** tab -> under **List View**, enable **Allow folders to be expanded**

#### Or via CLI

1. Enable list view

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences default-folder-viewer 'list-view'
   ```
2. Enable tree view

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.list-view use-tree-view true
   ```

Answer (score 3):

In nautilus-3.6 (raring), it's gone though I've added back along with several other changes in a ppa
https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/nautilus-hacks

In 3.8 or higher it's been returned, enabled thru - click on files > preferences > Display > & enable there.

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu 18.04 gnome-shell 3.28**

Use this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.list-view use-tree-view true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the tree view, called as "list view" by clicking via View -> List.

The same can be done by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> To revert back press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>1</kbd>

[image: List view]