# Is there a Linux file manager with a proper drop-down tree view? (like finder in OS X)

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, filemanager

As a happy Linux user for almost a year now, this is the bane of my existence. Does the Linux community hate tree views for some obscure reason?

I don't mean a tree view in the side panel. That's useless. I mean a *proper* tree view, such that, when I click the triangle, all files and subdirectories contained within the directory show beneath, and I can drag and drop files, open and close trees.

It is extremely frustrating to navigate and move files around deeply nested directories without this feature.

I've tried: Nautilus, PCManFM, emelFM2, Krusader. I find it hard to believe that even crazilly-full-featured file managers like Krusader would be missing this most obvious of features... and yet, here I am.  For all the effort put into those file managers, is this so far-fetched to ask for?

[image]

I just need a simple, single-pane file manager with a tree view option. Help!

And -- please -- HOW IS THIS FUNCTION INVOKED ?? 
(Do I left/right click while pressing control/alt/shift?
Is some setting required?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Dolphin](http://dolphin.kde.org/features.html) appears to have this capability.

[image: dophin]

Answer (score 24):

Nautilus does this.

### Ubuntu up to version 12.10

- Just switch to `View > List`.

[image: nautilus]

### Ubuntu 13.04

Feature is missing in this release

### Ubuntu 13.10 and newer

- activate `Preferences > Display > Navigate folders in a tree`
- switch to List View

[image: nautilus]

Comment: Pretty same as OSX, I didn't know that.
Nice to know!

Comment: Not anymore: http://askubuntu.com/questions/256986/how-to-achieve-list-tree-view-in-nautilus -- because convergence. By far the dumbest decision anyone has ever made... actually merging a commit that *removes* functioning code for a useful feature, because it's not as useful on some device that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Bummer! Didn't know that. Sorry. One more reason not to update to 13.04...

Comment: Nah, it's still there. Preferences > Display > Navigate folders in a tree. Might have been missing for one release, though.

Comment: still there in 15.10

Comment: it's there : files -> preferences -> allow folders to be expanded

Answer (score 15):

You could use Marlin as well https://launchpad.net/marlin

[image]

Install with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marlin-devs/marlin-daily
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install marlin marlin-plugin-*
```

**UPDATE** : haven't tested this, but it should work to set Marlin as the default file manager.

```
xdg-mime default Marlin.desktop inode/directory
```

Comment: very sexy indeed!

Comment: For Ubuntu 14.04 you need to use a different ppa ``ppa:noobslab/apps``

Comment: how to set it up as your default file manager?

Comment: check my post again, I updated it.