# How do I show a directory tree in the GUI

Tags: directory

New to Ubuntu.  Just installed V.16 + updates.

In Windows 10 the left hand pane of the directory view can show a tree the relationship between various folders.  I find this useful.  Does the same facility exist in Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you want a tree view on left sidebar?

Comment: On the left sidebar of the window which looks and files and folders in the current directory, yes.  It would be OK if it were somewhere else though.

Comment: This is answered here: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/339125/is-there-a-linux-file-manager-with-a-proper-drop-down-tree-view-like-finder-in

Comment: I use a file manager called thunar