# Tree-like content display in Nautilus

Tags: 13.10, nautilus, nautilus-elementary

Is there a way to have OS X-like behavior in Nautilus? Nautilus elementary is long gone?

Basically I'd like to have an option to a tree view (only 2 views, not multiple like in max os x) where the parent will be on the left, and the content on the right.

On Mac OS X, it looks like this

[image]

Possible something similar on Ubuntu?

Comment: Please check if [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/398093/177437) brings up what you need.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa Yes, this is a kind of a tree :). But not useful like on Mac. If it can reach to double click or single click, but it does not.

Comment: I guess I misinterpreted your question. You might want to decorate your question with an image so that non Mac users like me can be better understand.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa You were right. Just updated it. Thanks

Comment: @AvinashRaj That's not the tree view asked for in this question. This question is asking for a column like tree view

Comment: Gnome's file manager worked like this back in the 1990s. I far prefer the tree view Nautilus had up to 3.4.