# What happened to drop-down folders?

Tags: 14.04, directory, ubuntu-studio

In Ubuntu version 12.10 in the file manager there were drop down folders What happened to them?
Were they removed? if so how may I recreate them?

I just installed UbuntuStudio 14.041 on a Compaq (32bit installation)

UbuntuStudio uses Thunar and XCFE. THere must be a way to add this into THunar. It such a basic feature that has been part of Mac and Windows for over a decade.
How can i add/correct this in Thunar.

Ubuntu claims Thunar is light and faster than Nautilus. I tried adding Nautilus, it made such a mess. I had to completely re-install UbuntuStudio 14.04. Right now, I am keeping all my data in an external HD (using Backup)

Comment: By drop down folders you mean?

Comment: Do you mean this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/256986/how-to-achieve-list-tree-view-in-nautilus

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes! There must be a way to do this in Thunar and XFCE

Comment: Follow UP. Nautilus was a disaster. I tried one suggestion of installing Dolphin file manager. Dolphin works great! better than nautilus for me.I then switched Dolphin as the default. I still have to use Thunar to access USB mounted devices though